# Mail and cookie are not working together?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

Please read my post before making it duplicate?

Yesterday one of the developer helped me to solve cookie issue but after adding that code my form not sending any mail to admin and form filler. The problem i was facing yesterday that i was not able to access cookie immediately.

Previous code :

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) || isset($_POST['username'])){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('a.down').show().css("display", "block");
        });
    </script>
<?php } else {  include('login.php'); } ?>
```

My Current Code :

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
    setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    $username=$_POST['username'];
}
?>

<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) || isset($username)){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('a.down').show().css("display", "block");
        });
    </script>
<?php } else { include('login.php'); ?>
```

Thanks for your time.

My cookie code is working now and i am able to submit form in one time but the problem is i am not getting mails.

here my login.php file code :

```
<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
        setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
       $username=$_POST['username'];
       }
?>

<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) || isset($username)){ ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('a.down-resources').show().css("display", "block");
        });
    </script>

<?php } else { 

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  

    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['phone'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];  
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];

    if ($username == $_POST['username'] && $email == $_POST['email']){
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                echo "$email is not a valid email address";
            }

        $udomain = end(explode('@', $email));

        $domains = array("aol.com", "att.net", "comcast.net",
            "facebook.com", "gmail.com", "gmx.com", "googlemail.com", "google.com",
            "hotmail.com", "hotmail.co.uk", "mac.com", "me.com", "mail.com", "msn.com",
            "live.com", "sbcglobal.net", "verizon.net", "yahoo.com", "yahoo.co.uk",
            "email.com", "games.com", "gmx.net", "hush.com", "hushmail.com", "inbox.com",
            "lavabit.com", "love.com", "pobox.com", "rocketmail.com", "safe-mail.net",
            "wow.com", "ygm.com", "ymail.com", "zoho.com", "fastmail.fm", "bellsouth.net",
            "charter.net", "cox.net", "earthlink.net", "juno.com",
            "btinternet.com", "virginmedia.com", "blueyonder.co.uk", "freeserve.co.uk",
            "live.co.uk", "ntlworld.com", "o2.co.uk", "orange.net", "sky.com",
            "talktalk.co.uk", "tiscali.co.uk", "virgin.net", "wanadoo.co.uk", "bt.com",
            "sina.com", "qq.com", "naver.com", "hanmail.net", "daum.net", "nate.com",
            "yahoo.co.jp", "yahoo.co.kr", "yahoo.co.id", "yahoo.co.in", "yahoo.com.sg",
            "yahoo.com.ph", "hotmail.fr", "live.fr", "laposte.net", "yahoo.fr",
            "wanadoo.fr", "orange.fr", "gmx.fr", "sfr.fr", "neuf.fr", "free.fr",
            "gmx.de", "hotmail.de", "live.de", "online.de", "t-online.de", "web.de",
            "yahoo.de", "mail.ru", "rambler.ru", "yandex.ru", "hotmail.be", "live.be",
            "skynet.be", "voo.be", "tvcablenet.be", "hotmail.com.ar", "live.com.ar",
            "yahoo.com.ar", "fibertel.com.ar", "speedy.com.ar", "arnet.com.ar",
            "hotmail.com", "gmail.com", "yahoo.com.mx", "live.com.mx", "yahoo.com",
            "hotmail.es", "live.com", "hotmail.com.mx", "prodigy.net.mx", "msn.com");


        if (in_array($udomain, $domains)) {
            echo "Only use corporate email address";
        } else {
            define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
            setcookie("username", $username, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");          
            /* send to 1st recipient */
            $to_1 = "example@yahoo.com";
            $from = "$email";
            $subject_1 = "Test";
            $message_1 = "Hello World!";

            $headers_1 = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
            $headers_1 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers_1 .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";

            mail($to_1, $subject_1, $message_1, $headers_1);

            /* send to 2nd recipient */
            $to_2 = "$email";
            $from_2 = "example@test.com";
            $subject_2 = "Thank you";
            $message_2 ="2nd Message to visitor";

            $headers_2 = 'From: ' . $from_2 . "\r\n";
            $headers_2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers_2 .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";

            mail($to_2, $subject_2, $message_2, $headers_2);
            header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        }  

        } else { echo 'Some Error Occured'; }  
    }  else { echo '<strong>Please enter the require fields.</strong> <br /> <br />'; }
}
?>

<p>To access complete information, please fill-in the form below and click on submit button. <br /></p>

<form action="" method="POST">
        Name * :<input name="username" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo $username;}?>">
        Email * :<input name="email" type="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo $email;}?>">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"><br />
        Company :<input name="company" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo $company;}?>">
        Phone * :<input name="phone" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo $phone;}?>">
    </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried sending test email from your serving just to check you mails are working or not??

Comment: Yeah i did that and that's working fine.

Comment: why are you saving your your variable as string; remove the double quotes from your "$email". and check again.

Comment: change this $to_2 = "$email";  to $to_2 = $email; i meant

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but that's not working.

Comment: Replace this code in your second mail function. if(!mail("your_email_id","Test Subject","Test Body")){ echo "Not send"; }else{ echo "sent"; } Replace "your_email_id" with your personal email. If this works than check your variables and headers thoroughly.

Comment: Actually before adding this code my script was running perfectly and sending the mail.

<?php 
if(!isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
    setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    $username=$_POST['username'];
}
?>

<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) || isset($username)){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('a.down').show().css("display", "block");
        });
    </script>
<?php } else { include('login.php'); ?>

Comment: But the problem is without this code my form require two time submission because cookie didn't available immediately.

Comment: Any error logs generated on your server?

Comment: No I didn't find any error logs on server.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Just now i have checked the error log on server and found this warning. 

"Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0". 

does it blocking the script to send mail?

Comment: yeah i have tried your suggestion but still the result is same i haven't received any mail

Comment: @RonakRathod $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA will this cause any problem?

Comment: No that is not causing it.

Comment: @KyleE4K i have try your suggestion but still result is same.

Comment: Is there any way we can solve this problem by using session and cookie together?